# IOS PASSBOOK - error while create multiple PKPass for Passbook

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook

I am working on passbook feature for creating Boarding pass in iOS,  I am able to create a single boarding pass and it is working well, but while tying to create multiple passes, I am getting the following issues:

1. I am able to get the counts but all passes are being replaced with last one while REVIEW
2. After selecting SAVE ALL, there is only one pass in passbook app, i.e the last one.

I am using Following code to show passes

```
-(void) initializeWithMultiPassbookArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrPasses
{
    NSMutableArray *arrPKPass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(NSString *path in arrPasses)
    {
        NSData *data;

        if(path && path.length)
        {
            data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

            NSError *error;

            PKPass *passSample = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];

            if(passSample)
            {
                [arrPKPass addObject:passSample];
                passSample = nil;
            }
            else
                JALog(@"passSample is nil");
        }
        else
        {
            JALog(@"Error occured while fetching pkpass data from cache path");
        }
    }

    if(arrPKPass && arrPKPass.count > 1)
    {
        if(!self.passLibrary)
            self.passLibrary = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];

        __weak BookingSuccessfulViewController *self_ = self;
        if(viewPopUpBg)
        {
            [viewPopUpBg removeFromSuperview];
            viewPopUpBg = nil;
        }
        [self.passLibrary addPasses:arrPKPass withCompletionHandler:^(PKPassLibraryAddPassesStatus status) {

            switch (status) {
                case PKPassLibraryDidAddPasses:
                {
                    [App_Delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(RemoveLoader) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                    if([self_ respondsToSelector:@selector(showAlertFor:withMsg:withTag:)])
                        [self_ showAlertFor:SAVED withMsg:@"Your booking details have been added to Passbook." withTag:0];
                    break;
                }
                case PKPassLibraryDidCancelAddPasses:
                {

                    [App_Delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(RemoveLoader) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

                    break;
                }
                case PKPassLibraryShouldReviewPasses:
                {
                    //[self_ performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(RemoveLoader) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                    [App_Delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(RemoveLoader) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];


                    PKAddPassesViewController *vcPKAddPass = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPasses:arrPKPass];
                    [vcPKAddPass setDelegate:(id)self_];
                    [self_ presentViewController:vcPKAddPass animated:YES completion:nil];
                    vcPKAddPass = nil;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }];
    }
    else if(arrPKPass.count == 1)
    {
        if(viewPopUpBg)
        {
            [viewPopUpBg removeFromSuperview];
            viewPopUpBg = nil;
        }

        [App_Delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(RemoveLoader) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        PKPass *passLocal = [arrPKPass objectAtIndex:0];

        if(passLocal)
        {
            self.currentPass = passLocal;

            //present view controller to add the pass to the library
            PKAddPassesViewController *vcPKAddPass = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:passLocal];
            [vcPKAddPass setDelegate:(id)self];
            [self presentViewController:vcPKAddPass animated:YES completion:nil];
            vcPKAddPass = nil;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        JALog(@"arrPKPass is nil");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `arrPasses` contains unique paths and is not an array containing the same path multiple times?

Comment: Yes, all have different paths. I think there must be one key which should be different for each pass, For now I am trying with "serialNumber" key while creating JSON

Answer (score 0):

Got my ans:

Every Pass should contain different serial No in the key "serialNumber" while creating JSON

Also Check the Capabilities in Project>Target>Capabilities>Passbook

**Allow subset of pass types** is selected with specific identifiers.

These steps worked for me.

Hopefully help to others also.

Thanks